# Displaying a WPF context menu after a D&D operation

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, contextmenu

Here is my problem; I want to display a context menu, with items created on the fly in the code  behind, when a D&D operation has finished.

What I can't do is

1. Insert an item that will cancel cancel the drop operation, if selected
2. I can't find a way to keep the menu open when I click anywhere outside of the menu

How can I do these two things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying the context menu will not block the D&D operation from completing, so it won't wait until the user addresses the context menu.  You would have to somehow save the D&D action (capture what is being dropped and hold on to it) and wait to complete the action until after the context menu has been addressed.

A context menu will automatically close when it loses focus.  However there is a [StaysOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.staysopen.aspx) property that overrides this behavior.  If you set `StaysOpen` to `true`, it will remain open until you explicitly close it (by settings `IsOpen` to `false`).

Comment: Thanks Brian that is what I did. Intercepted the selection of an item called Cancel and basically discarded the dropped data. I knew about the StaysOpen property but if you change window it does close. Fortunately the customer did not expect this feature.